# Font Awesome showing in the browser but not in any android device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have added font awesome to my **ionic 1 app** , I have created fonts folder and reference the style sheet in the HTML page ,

The icons showing in the browser but not showing in any **android device**.

[image: this is the files and code used]

Comment: We need any relevant HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: I have created a Fonts folder and i have added "SVG , eot , ttf , woff " files to this folder and in my HTML i have added this "<link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> " , in the view i used the <i> tag , it works perfect in the browser but later on after i build APK , nothing showing

Comment: Could you please post at the _bare minimum_ a screen shot? Without any HTML or CSS is is almost impossible for us to test and correct your issue.

Comment: I have attached screen shot for the files structure and the CSS file content along with <i> tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the font file for FontAwesome, say **fontawesome.ttf**. Next, what you have to do is just include that file in your CSS file. Here I will assume that both the CSS file and the font file are located in the same directory.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  src:         url(fontawesome.ttf);
}
```

Now you can use FontAwesome throughout your application or webpage by just setting the `font-family` property to `FontAwesome` whereever needed.

Comment: i already did this in my CSS file    font-family: 'fontawesome';
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved, please follow this link [Use Font Awesome Glyph Icons With Ionic Framework](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/use-font-awesome-glyph-icons-ionicframework/)

, to get bigger size icons you need to add this line to your CSS file

```
font-size: 25px !important;
```

Thank you everyone for your support.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was:

Go to /bower_components/font_awesome/scss/variables

change $fa-font-path to $fa-font-path: "../**assets**/fonts" !default;